# nvarchar error message

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, nvarchar

I built a small project in ASP.NET with SQL Server database. When I view it in browser or debugging my project everything works well. But when I type something to my form and click to send I have error message

> *Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'.
>
>   Specification: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax
>   near 'nvarchar'.*

In my database I have table with values:

```
Name      nvarchar(50) 
Mail      nvarchar(200) 
Message   nvarchar(MAX)
```

In my source, FormView I also defined maximal length (in EditItemTemplate, InsertItemTemplate, ItemTemplate).

```
Name   MaxLength="<%# 50 %>"  
Mail   MaxLength="<%# 200 %>"  
Message TextMode="MultiLine"
```

Code for saving into table:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table1]"
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Name], [Mail], [Message]) VALUES (@Name, @Mail, @Message)">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Mail" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Message" />
        </InsertParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

When I saw references it should be ok... should be there also problems with allowing nulls?

Comment: where is your code to save to the table ?

Comment: The error is coming from the SQL you are using to interact with the database (the exception type indicates this). As Shyju states above, you'll need to supply the SQL to get help on this.

Comment: I wrote there also my code for saving into table.